# what $H^1_q$ is?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, definition, sobolev-spaces

I don't know the meaning of the notation $H^1_q$ (a Sobolev space)?
Where I can find the exact definition of that notation?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A good resource for all things Sobolev-space related is *Sobolev Spaces* by R. A. Adams and J. J. F. Fournier, $2^\mathrm{nd}$ edition.  Page $60$ there provides the definition that you're looking for:

$$H^m_q = H^{m,q}(\Omega) \equiv \mbox{the completion of } \{u\in C^m(\Omega) \mid \|u\|_{m,q} \lt \infty \}  $$
where the completion is with respect to the norm $\|u\|_{m,q}$.

In fact, as was proven in a paper by Myers and Serrin with the famously short title [H=W](https://www.jstor.org/stable/72114?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) , the spaces $H^{m,q}$ and $W^{m,q}$ are the same so most of the time a choice between $H$ and $W$ will be entirely stylistic.